# how to make array to string conversion in Php? CLOSED

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
        include 'dbconnection.php';

        if(isset($_REQUEST['id']))
        {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $sqlLoader="Select Name from validpersonnel where id=?";
        $resLoader=$db->prepare($sqlLoader);
        $resLoader->execute(array($id));
        while($rowLoader = $resLoader->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $name=$rowLoader['Name'];
        }
        echo $name; //line 61
        }

        //echo $id;
        /*$sql="SELECT Name FROM validPersonnel WHERE PersonnelID = :id"
        $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT Name FROM validPersonnel WHERE PersonnelID = :id');
        $query->execute(array('id' => $id));
        foreach($query as $row)
        {
            echo $row['id']; 
        } */
?>
```

error message

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\v1.2\login_pane\login_pane-personnelselect\profile\profile.php on line 61
>   Call Stack

how can i get rid of it?

Comment: That means `$name` is an array. Try `print_r($name)` instead. Does it look like what you expect it to be?

Comment: no it does not. i want to have a clean printed string

Comment: Add the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($name, true).'</pre>';` to the question.

Comment: it displayed 

Array
(
    [Address] => 8016 Roxas Avenue, Davao City, Philippines
)

Comment: how can i make it to only display "8016 Roxas Avenue, Davao City, Philippines"?

Comment: Change `$name=$rowLoader['Name'];` to `$name=$rowLoader['Name']['Address'];`.

Comment: Array
(
    [Address] => 8016 Roxas Avenue, Davao City, Philippines
)

the same output how come it displayed the address? i want to have the name to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sqlLoader="Select Name from validpersonnel where id=?";
$resLoader=$db->prepare($sqlLoader);
$resLoader->execute(array($id));
$row = $resLoader->fetch();
echo $row['Name'];
```

REMEMBER, for one row use just

```
$resLoader->fetch();
```

Comment: it displayed none. however i check my id an it is the same id from my db.

Comment: what about `try{ $resLoader->execute(); } catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }`???

Comment: and one important point in connection to DB is `ATTR_ERRMODE`:
`$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);`